# Can I write a variable sized array with this code?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Can I write a variable sized array using the following code?

I have executed it on Fedora. I used a pointer `a` and integer `b` to create the array,
so can I say that this array is a dynamic array?

```
main()
{
    int * const a;  
    int b;
    a[b];     
    b=5;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
     printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does "I have executed it on Fedora" mean you were able to compile this?

Comment: `b` isn't initialized before used and no, you can't do this (at least not in C89).

Comment: If you want a dynamic array, why not use malloc?

Comment: @Jongware Yes i compiled it on fedora

Comment: Make sure to crank up the Warning level for your compiler, preferably to its maximum, and compile it again. Then first fix the *obvious* errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't create variable-length array using this code. When you use

```
int b;
```

`b` can have any value. It can be 0, 4294967295, or any other number. Then, when you use

```
a[b];
```

`a` can have any random length each time use execute the program.

Next thing:
`a` will not change it's size when you change `b` value:

```
int b = 5;
int a[b];
b = 6;
// Length of `a` is still 5.
```

If you want to change size of array after it's been created, you should read about `malloc()` and `realloc()` functions and use them.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of that program is undefined.

You never actually allocate an array; `a` is just a dangling pointer that may or may not point to a valid memory address.  Until you initialize that pointer, any attempt to dereference it is undefined.  You also use `b` before you initialize it; that usage is also undefined.  If you try to execute that program, the most likely result is a crash.

So to answer your question, no, that is not a valid way to create a variable-sized array.

Comment: Fortunately OP *reads* from `a` but never *writes* to it. That may be about the only reason it does not crash and burn.